# How to upload entire Code's folder to AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

How to upload a project folder to **AWS CodeCommit** repository? I can see that I can only upload a single file from the CodeCommit console. Is it possible to upload all the items in the folder (Entire folder) at once?

Comment: Are you asking how to use git, or something else?

Comment: Not git, from CodeCommit console how can we upload the entire project folder?

Comment: The CodeCommit console doesn't appear to support the upload of a folder. Use git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeCommit console is primarily for managing repositories, their branches, approval rules, etc., but not for interacting with the content of the git-based repositories themselves. For committing files or directories, the appropriate git command (`git add` etc.) is more feasible than using the AWS Console, CLI or API.

However, if this is primarily about initializing a repository with a blueprint or project template, you can also upload the content to S3 and create a new CodeCommit repository using CloudFormation, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codecommit-repository-s3.html).